# Busybox boot error and resolving dependencies

Tags: boot, dependencies, update-manager, busybox

I went from a windows7/ubuntu dual boot to solo Ubuntu a couple of days ago. I reinstalled the whole hard drive from a live usb. Now, most of the times I boot busybox prevents from booting, and boots in the initramfs console. 
I can solve it by exiting the initramfs console with `exit` and the do an fsck

```
fsck /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root -y
```

and then just `reboot`

This solves the busybox problem but it keeps coming back. 
I would like to find a permanent solution for the problem and learn more about linux since I am pretty noob but keen to learn.

I also have an error regarding downloaded packages to update my software as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpChq.png)

I then tried doing it in the terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

But no upgrade as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaN3p.png)

I tried to empty my cache, change the download source in software center from australian server to main server and several options that I found online trying to resolve it, but no success thus far. I don't know if the 2 problems are connected.

Comment: One question per thread, please. It's very unlikely somebody in the future will have both your problems at once.

Comment: Maybe they are related?